# $wpdb The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to push some data to a custom table in my Wordpress install, but I am getting the error `The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders` and I'm not sure why. Here is my query:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO products
        (`name`, `color`, `price`) 
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        price = %s',
    $name,
    $color,
    $price
);
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

The exact error is this:

> **Notice**: Function wpdb::prepare was called **incorrectly**. The query does
> not contain the correct number of placeholders (4) for the number of
> arguments passed (3).

I am not sure why it is looking for 4 placeholders, because I am only trying to insert/update 3 columns, so it should only be looking for 3 placeholders/arguments.

Comment: You have 3 placeholders under `VALUES` and 1 under `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. That makes 4.

Comment: @vancoder ahhh, that makes sense. So if there is a row where the "name" already exists, I would just like to update that row with only the new price. How would I refactor the ON DUPLICATE KEY statement to accomplish that? Do I just add the price field again into VALUES?

Comment: You just need to add the 4th placeholder, which would be `$price` again, no?  Because all you're doing is inserting a row, but if the row already exists, you just update the price rather than re-insert all the data, so your 4th placeholder is just `$price` again.